# Escape symbol in documentdb query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How do I query on a property that contains a '-' symbol.

Specifically I want to perform this query:

```
SELECT * FROM c.inside.abs-humid
```

But this gives me an error.

Querying on properties without dash is working perfectly fine, how do i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DocumentDB uses JSON notation for escaping property names. Try:

`SELECT * FROM c.inside["abs-humid"]`

Comment: I need to query on a specific attribute value, to facilitate a partial-name, case insensitive search. Value in the doc-attribute is `"Team WBH/Grayscale"` the following query does not yield any result: `SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(UPPER(c.name, 'WBH/GRAY'))`and I provide a partial string `"WBH/Gray"`. It is because of the forward slash, because partial name searches without the special character works just fine. Any ideas?